# get static function to return async value

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, es6-promise

I want a static ES6 method to simply return a value instead of a promise. This is what I am trying to do.

```
export default class Member {

  static existingMember() {
    var _existingMember;
    // DB.findExistingMember() -> returns a promise
    DB.findExistingMember().then(member => {
      _existingMember = member
    })
    return _existingMember
  }
}

// in mocha test

describe('some test', function () => {
  const member = Member.existingMember()

  it('has access to member', function() => {
     // I want member to be available here instead of having to do member.then()
    console.log(member)
    foo.someFunction(member)
    bar.someFunction(member)
  })
})
```

Comment: How do you see that being possible given the variable you want returned, `_existingMember`, has its value set **asynchronously**?

Comment: @Mitya Within `then` at the point of setting, hasn't the value resolved?

Comment: Yes - but by that time your static method has already completed its flow and returned a variable with the value of undefined. Its value is not assigned until later, when the asynchronous flow completes.

Comment: @Mitya this is the exact problem I am trying to solve. Is there a way to set `existingMember` to return the value from inside the promise without `async-await`?

Comment: No - it's a contradiction. A function only ever returns a value synchronously unless you do something fancy with something like generators. Otherwise promises (of which `async-await` is an abstraction) or at least some form of callbacks are your only route.

Answer (score 1):

You can use await on the `Member.existingMember` function to use your `member` as normal variable

```
export default class Member {
    static existingMember() {
        return DB.findExistingMember();
    }
}

// in mocha test

describe('some test', function ()  {
    it('has access to member', async function () {
        const member = await Member.existingMember()
        console.log(member)
        foo.someFunction(member)
        bar.someFunction(member)
    })
})
```